# Firebase authentication from localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a web project and I'd like to use firebase authentication.

The problem is when I call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` it fails on CORS preflight check. The response contains https://localhost:3000 while my localhost is served over http. Is there an easy way to resolve this issue?

**EDIT:**
The full error message was:

```
Failed to load https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=<key>: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**UPDATE**

I ended up creating a cloud functions endpoint as I have to make some validated DB updates anyway.

Comment: Can you post the error you got from console?

Comment: @TiWang I added the full error

Comment: not a easy way... but you can try to generate a self signed certificate with openssl and associate to your localhost.